# Can't Init Crashlytics/Fabric in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to integrate Fabric into our Unity (2019.1.1f1) project but I am getting an error message at runtime when running in the editor:

> [Fabric] Couldn't find Crashlytics's GameObject

I followed the instructions in this tutorial: https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/installation.html

I found the CrashlyticsInit script, but no GameObject.

The Fabric/Prepare Fabric menu item has no effect.

I have not tried running on device.

Comment: While I dont have an account, id expect that as part of the "Fabric -> Prepare Fabric" option it creates some game objects and attaches a script to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin from Fabric/Firebase here - we recently brought out Unity support in Firebase Crashlytics and that's where we're focusing our development and support efforts going forward, so I definitely recommend checking out Firebase. We've also received a couple reports of the Fabric plugin not working with the recent Unity 2019 releases, so it's possible the recent versions aren't working with Fabric for Unity.

Here are the [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migrate-from-fabric) for getting from Fabric Unity to Firebase Crashlytics Unity/setting up with Firebase Crashlytics. Hope this helps!